# How to change embedded image in button on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML button that is setup like this:

How do I set the image color to red on hover to prevent it from disappearing?

https://jsfiddle.net/s7dLwp0r/

```css
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  background-color: red;
  height: 39px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"  alt="order"/>
&nbsp;order
</button>
```

Comment: I'd consider a different approach here: use an svg icon instead of an image. You give the browser a lot less work to do and yourself a lot more freedom; i.e. make one less server call or expensive base64 conversion (to render the image), allow yourself to leverage different psuedo-classes (like `:hover`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use invert filter on the hover of the button against the image.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLz4ptaq/2/)

for future changes, you can enter the color you want on [this](https://isotropic.co/hex-color-to-css-filter/) website and then use that as the filter

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #C40000;
  background-color: #C40000;
  height: 39px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #C40000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:hover>img {
  filter: invert(44%) sepia(100%) saturate(1313%) hue-rotate(312deg) brightness(93%) contrast(101%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"  alt="order"/>
&nbsp;order
</button>
```

Comment: that will make it black, busy with some code, trying to get it red for you.

Comment: @mplungjan see update and link, it works now as you wanted.

Comment: But what if you need to change it to green now (or some time in the near or far future)?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError see my second edit.

Answer (score 1):

I changed img color to black and used Den's approach.

```css
.btn {
  font: normal normal bold 13px/16px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background-color: #C40000;
  height: 39px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #C40000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #C40000;
  color: #C40000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn > img {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(123deg) brightness(104%) contrast(102%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover > img {
  filter: invert(17%) sepia(98%) saturate(2966%) hue-rotate(352deg) brightness(78%) contrast(127%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
&nbsp;order
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use an SVG as your image source and then define the fill colour as follows:

```
.btn:hover svg {
   fill: green;
}
```

Comment: This icon on FontAwesome is pretty close, and FA offers SVG versions: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/file-alt?style=solid